# Delphi and Threads

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a `TListView` filled from a `TRestRequest` with `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread`.
Everything works OK on the first run, but on `PulltoRefresh` it is not working (no Freezing, no Results). If I don't use Threads, it works fine with freezing.

Where is the problem when I use the same code except the `ListView.Items.Clear`?

Here is my code.

```pascal
procedure TForm4.Server;
var
  i, Id: Integer;
  UName, Descr,ThumbUrl: UnicodeString;
  LItem: TListViewItem;
begin
  FDMemTable1.EmptyDataSet;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      RESTClient1.BaseURL := {my PHP URL};
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
      FDMemTable1.First;
    
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        var
          i: integer;
        begin
          for i := 0 to FDMemTable1.RecordCount - 1 do
          begin
            Id := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('id').Value;
            UName := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('username').Value;
            Descr := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('descr').Value;
            ThumbUrl := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('image_url').Value;
            ListView1.BeginUpdate;
            LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
            LItem.Data['Id'] := Id;
            LItem.Data['UName'] := UName;
            LItem.Data['Descr'] := Descr;
            LItem.Data['ThumbUrl'] := ThumbUrl;
            LItem.Adapter.ResetView(LItem);
            ListView1.EndUpdate;
            FDMemTable1.Next;
          end;
        end
      );
    end
  ).Start;
end;
    
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadFormState;
  Server;
end;
    
procedure TForm4.ListView1PullRefresh(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
  Server;
end;
```

I have to mention the items created on `ListView1UpdatingObjects`. I test it on Android.

Comment: Never ever access the GUI from another thread, only from the main thread!!! Use ``TThread.Synchronize`` or ``TThread.Queue`` in your thread for this purpose.

Comment: @DelphiCoder that’s what he’s already doing...

Comment: Please take care for any exceptions inside the anonymous thread, because these don’t get shown, when not handled. Also use a try/finally after `Listview1.BeginUpdate`. One last point: is FDMemTablet connected to UI controls?

Comment: @R.Hoek oh sorry, missed that line of code somehow! :(

Comment: @R. Hoek The table is connected just to Rest controls. I take the results to vars.

Comment: Did you set ListView1.PullToRefresh to True ?

Comment: I would move variables that are used only inside thread into thread : Id: Integer;
  UName, Descr,ThumbUrl: UnicodeString;
  LItem: TListViewItem;

Comment: also try to make RestClient, RestRequest and Memtable in code inside thread if its used only for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I must clear ListView1.Items bitmaps first and then to delete the item, like this.

```
procedure TForm4.ListView1PullRefresh(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  AItem: TListViewItem;
  iBitmap: TListItemImage;
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListView1.OnPaint := nil;
    while ListView1.Items.Count > 0 do
    begin
      iBitmap := ListView1.Items[0].Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemImage>('MImage');
      if (Assigned(iBitmap) and iBitmap.OwnsBitmap) then
      begin
        iBitmap.Bitmap.Free;
        iBitmap.Bitmap := nil;
      end;
      ListView1.Items.Delete(0);
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
    Server;
  end;
```

Next, set `ListView1.OnPaint := ListView1Paint` somewhere in your code;